# How do I link two apps in node.js and rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, real-time

I run a social network app built in ruby on rails 4. We want to improve it and add realtime and add live streaming features. We also want  to make 'likes', 'comments' features real time. My lead programer says ruby on rails is not good for this and not possible and only way is to do it in node.js however doesnt know any solution to link node.js application to rails. I'm a business guy and not technical and need info to let him know it can be done.

Comment: This is a very broad question and moreover I'm not even sure you couldn't do it in rails: https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable

Comment: Firing him would be the best solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 doesn't have streaming(like websocket, maybe streaming is not good word in this context) functional from box, but many gems exist for this: https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=websocket.
However you can use websocket.io if you decide it is a better solution, for example, in my current project we use websocket.io for send a notifications for mobile application through websocket: rails and nodejs exchanging data through Redis.

Comment: we are looking for solution to add live video streaming, live chat and live notifications. We are currently in rails 4 and wanted to upgrade to 5